# How to display a form submit success message when the PHP is in a separate file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm so sorry to post this question when there are so many existing questions already on here, but I'm really struggling with my PHP form handling and feel like I am going around in circles.  I'd really appreciate some straight answers if possible.

I have an index.php file with a form in it `<form id="contact-form" class="form" method="post" action="form.php">` and a form.php file that takes the form entries and sends an email.  I have a redirect from form.php back to index.php#contactanchor after the email has been sent. That's all working ok.

```
//Send the email!
if (!$nameErr && !$emailErr && !$phoneErr && !$commentsErr) {
  $email_body = "Name: $name\n Email: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message: $comments\n";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
    if (mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) {
      $result = "Thank you for your enquiry.";
    } else {
      $result = "Submission error. Please check your details.";
    }
}

header('Location: index.php#contactanchor');
```

I'm trying to get a message to appear in a div on index.php depending on whether the email was sent properly.

```
<div class="formresponse">
 <p class="paragraph">I would like the response to show up here</p>
</div>
```

The message is in a variable $result in form.php.

(1) Firstly, do I need to add `<?php session_start(); ?>` to the top of index.php?

(2) How do I get the div in index.php to reflect the text from the $result variable?

I (lightly) appreciate the differences between server and client-side operations and realise that I need to use some Javascript or AJAX, but I'm at a loss as to where to put code and what code to use. I'd really appreciate some help... I've read through so many questions and answers today that my head is battered and I could really do with some coddling :-(

Comment: Stick the `$result` in a session variable, and have `index.php` look to see if there's anything in that session variable, and display it if there is. You can do it with JS / Ajax, but you don't have to - as long as both PHP scripts have `session_start()` you should be able to transfer the session variable as required. If you're calling `form.php` using Ajax, then it's different again, you can just `echo` the response and that will come back to your calling JS code, where you can then insert it into your div as part of the `success()` function.

Comment: Fabulous.  I thought there must be a way of setting 'global' variables but wasn't able to find anything as succinct as this.  Thank you.  Regarding the session itself, presumably I should unset it and destroy it afterwards?  If so, where would I place these functions in the grand scheme of things so that I don't lose the session variable message?

Comment: You should delete it after you've displayed it, IMO. As soon as you don't need it, clear it.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do that without wiping the $result message before they've had time to view it?  Copy it into an HTML variable first maybe?  Also, do I need to put  the unset/destroy functions in both the index.php file and the form.php file?

Comment: If you unset it in `form.php` and then redirect back to `index.php` so that they can fill the form in again, it won't be there when you get to `index.php`. So you must unset it after you have displayed it, which will be in `index.php` surely? Code in `index.php` will see if it exists when it is drawing your formresponse div - if it does, it should display then unset it, if it does not, then there's nothing to unset.